# Having 1 Slick table class per file and definition of foreign key

Tags: scala, slick

I am having a looking at Slick 2.0

In [this tutorial](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/gettingstarted.html), the schema is as below:

```
// Definition of the SUPPLIERS table
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers] //Definition TableQuery for suppliers

// Definition of the COFFEES table
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  def * = (name, supID, price, sales, total)
  // A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
  def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, suppliers)(_.id) // Supplier defined above
}
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
```

Here, the definition of the `TableQuery[Suppliers]` is done in the same file as the definition of `Coffee` so we can supply a `TableQuery` for the foreignKey (`supplier`)

Now, I would like to keep each class in a file and create the `TableQuery` whereever I need .

**My question is:**

How should I go to define the foreign key in the `Coffee` class and keep in a seperate file the `Suppliers` class?

Do I have to create those `TableQuery` in an Scala object and import it the `Suppliers` class so that I can provide a  `TableQuery` to the foreignKey definition ?

I hope I was clear enough :/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply reference the `TableQuery` to which the foreign key relates to:

```
// SuppliersSchema.scala
object SuppliersSchema {

  class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
    /* Omitted for brevity */
  }
  val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers] //Definition TableQuery for suppliers
}

// CoffeesSchema.scala
object CoffeesSchema {
  class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
    /* Omitted for brevity */

    def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, SuppliersSchema.suppliers)(_.id) // define in another file
  }

  val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
}
```

Another way would be to create a `TableQuery` reference to `Suppliers` inside of `CoffeesSchema` and use that in your foreign key definition key, anyway this approach is untested as I personally prefer the first one.

Comment: New versions of Play/slick use a different layout eg https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.7.x/play-scala-slick-example/app/models/PersonRepository.scala -  splitting the Table/TableQuery out into an object doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: I'm actually quite confident that this would still work, your link doesn't show that much difference on how the tables are defined.

Comment: thanks will try again.  Had various issues around the imports (dbConfig._ . and profile.api._) when splitting the Tables/TableQuery into objects but will revisit...